# Do certificates have to be manually added to client machines?

Tags: wcf, deployment, certificate, clickonce, x509certificate

I am deploying a WCF based application that uses mutual-authentication, for this reason certificates need to be installed on the clients machine, I assume this must be done so manually? If not, what other options do I have? The software is being distributed internally via ClickOnce. Is it possible to distribute the certificate upon the software first being installed (automatically)?

Comment: ClickOnce and Client Certificates are not really related. As Shiraz Bhaiji stated, you can push a certificate (presumably a CA) to every machine on the domain. But you would not do that for each client certificate because there would be too many one-off policies and one-off installers for each machine. Plus, the client certificate is usually issued during enrollment or provisioning; and not during install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it is an internal Application and you have a Windows domain.

Then you can distribute the certificates using a domain policy. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772491.aspx